# No se puede leer la propiedad 'addEventListener' con un submit de null

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un listado en javascript y html, no consigo solventar el ese error.

```js
var formPeliculas = document.querySelector("#formularioP");
formPeliculas.addEventListener('submit', function(){
var input = document.querySelector("#addmovie").value;
if (input.length >= 1) {
  localStorage.setItem(input, input);

}
});

for(var i in localStorage){
  console.log(localStorage[i]);
if(typeOf(localStorage[i]) == 'string') {
  var movList = document.querySelector("#peliculasList");
    var li = document.createELement("li");
    li.append(localStorage[i]);
    movList.append(li);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Base de datos de peliculas</h1>
    <h2>Añade tu pelicula:</h2>
    <form class="" action="" id="#formularioP">
      <input type="text" id="addmovie"/>
      <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <div class="" id="peliculas">
      <h2>Peliculas</h2>
      <ul id="peliculasList">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="ls.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

A ver si alguien con más experiencia (estoy aprendiendo poco a poco por mi cuenta) puede ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Creo que debes evitar el comportamiento por defecto con event.preventDefault()

Comment: @JoelIbaceta podrías explicar eso?

Comment: Un formulario tiene un evento submit que por defecto envia todo el contenido al destino definido en la propiedad action, si lo que quieres es añadir funcionalidad antes de eso, debes prevenir o evitar que se envite el formulario hasta que ... se cumplan tus condiciones, para eso se usa preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar `querySelector`, utiliza `getElementById`:

```js
var formPeliculas = document.getElementById("#formularioP");
formPeliculas.addEventListener('submit', function(){
var input = document.querySelector("#addmovie").value;
if (input.length >= 1) {
  localStorage.setItem(input, input);

}
});

for(var i in localStorage){
  console.log(localStorage[i]);
if(typeOf(localStorage[i]) == 'string') {
  var movList = document.querySelector("#peliculasList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(localStorage[i]);
    movList.append(li);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Base de datos de peliculas</h1>
    <h2>Añade tu pelicula:</h2>
    <form class="" action="" id="#formularioP">
      <input type="text" id="addmovie"/>
      <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <div class="" id="peliculas">
      <h2>Peliculas</h2>
      <ul id="peliculasList">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="ls.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Con el getElementById he solucionado el error de la línea 2 pero ahora tengo otro error en la línea 13: _Uncaught TypeError: document.createELement is not a function_

Comment: Tienes un typo.  Tienes la `L` mayuscula en `createELement`

Comment: Oh... gracias por tener tanta paciencia

Answer (score 0):

```js
var formPeliculas = document.getElementById("#formularioP");
formPeliculas.addEventListener('submit', function(){
var input = document.querySelector("#addmovie").value;
if (input.length >= 1) {
  localStorage.setItem(input, input);

}
});

for(var i in localStorage){
  console.log(localStorage[i]);
if(typeOf(localStorage[i]) == 'string') {
  var movList = document.querySelector("#peliculasList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(localStorage[i]);
    movList.append(li);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Base de datos de peliculas</h1>
    <h2>Añade tu pelicula:</h2>
    <form class="" action="" id="#formularioP">
      <input type="text" id="addmovie"/>
      <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <div class="" id="peliculas">
      <h2>Peliculas</h2>
      <ul id="peliculasList">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="ls.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```